# gradle - 'compile project(':X')' and defaultTasks?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, multi-project

Two projects in separate, parallel directories:

```
/Root/A/build.gradle
/Root/B/build.gradle
```

*A* is dependant on *B*:

```
// in /Root/A/build.gradle:
dependencies{
    compile project(':B')
    // ...
}
```

Both files define defaultTasks:

```
defaultTasks 'doWork'
```

The project's B default task *doWork* performs several tasks, e.g.:

```
task doWork {
     dependsOn 'build', 'some_task', 'other_task'
}
```

What's surprising: the set of tasks chosen to be executed from B is different depending on where the gradle is called from:

- the same for */Root/* and */Root/B/*,
- different for */Root/A* - smaller, none of the tasks defined in *doWork* get executed.

Question: is 'compile project(':X')' not calling defaultTasks? What task is it calling?